# how to install tornado for python of different version

Tags: python, centos, tornado

I'm using python on my CentOS7 server.
By default, there are python, python2, python2.7.

Then, I do `yum install tornado`. For now everything works fine.

Now I need to use python3.5 with tornado.

I've downloaded and installed python3.5 with its source code. But when I `python3.5 server.py`, I get an error:

> no module named 'tornado'

I've also tried `python3.5 -m pip install tornado` but I get an error:

> no module named pip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install pip with [ensurepip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html):

```
python3.5 -m ensurepip
```

Then:

```
python3.5 -m pip install tornado
```

Comment: I got an error: Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 7.1.2 requires SSL/TLS. I also did `yum install openssl-devel` but nothing changed.